# Add returned values to list in python?

Tags: python

When I print this I get:

```
FuncA
FuncB
FuncC
```

When really what I want is:

```
['FuncA', 'FuncB', 'FuncC']
```

How would I be able to iterate through my returned values and add them to the list?

Comment: so instead of printing do `list.append(...)`

Comment: By the way, do not use `list` as a variable name since it's a keyword in Python and it's a bad practice to override keywords.

Comment: Are you printing your `list` *in the loop*? Then yes, you get to see it being appended to. Print the list **when your loop is done**.

Comment: @User19437129: you are confusing *printing* (writing things to the console) with *returning*. The two are different concepts.

Comment: Oh, perfect, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually look for text (which can easily lead to false positives), use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to build an abstract syntax tree, then extract function names with that:

```
import ast

functions = []

with open( 'codefile.py', 'r') as file:
    tree = ast.parse(file.read(), 'codefile.py')
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
            functions.append(node.name)

print(functions)
```

This finds all function objects anywhere in the source code, just like your search for `def` text would have. Except this skips commented out code or the word `def` in a string literal, for instance.